# is it allowed to change enum field to text

Tags: mariadb

Maybe I am at the wrong stack, or this type of questions are not allowed.
But I have a table.column which has as type ENUM with a lot of values.
Since I try to change this (add more values) MariaDB server does not allow duplicate values. (MySQL server does)
I was thinking can I change the type of the field to TEXT without any danger of changing data or be 'punished' in any other way?

Removing duplicates are not possible cause there are 3 ENUM fields in the TABLE and the errors occurs in the 3 different fields.

Comment: Why do you want to add a duplicate value to an enum?

Comment: It is a system made by another company - and there were already duplicate values in that field. So adding values is impossible now :( - not in MySQL but in MariaDB it is

Comment: Fair enough. As long as you choose a text field which is wide enough to hold all possible enum values, there should be no problem. As always though, back up your tables before making such a change...